# JS синтаксис, что значит запятая

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как читать эту строку?

```
var cal = $(this).parent().parent(), col;
```

Что это за запятая?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В данном случае происходит объявление и инициализация переменных, которые идут списком. Фактически, это аналог следующего кода

```
var cal = $(this).parent().parent();
var col;
```

Comment: Имена переменных, конечно, отличные. Просто самодокументирующий код.

Answer (score 1):

Эм.. Перечисление при объявлении переменных.

```
var a, b;
var a = 32, b;
var a = $(this), b;
var a = $(this).parent(), b;
```